# Symfony Unit testing: How to simulate a Http-PUT with a json body?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, silex

I use the client-Object to simulate and test my Silex-Webservices. How can I send a JSON-Body with the PUT-method?

My idea was:

```
$crawler = $this->client->request('PUT', '/test', array(), array(), array(), '{"id":"34"}');
```

That does not work. :(

Answer (score 10):

Please try to use this code:

```
$client->request(
    'PUT', '/test', array(), array(),
    array(
        'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json',
        'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'
    ),
    '{"id":"34"}'
);
```

Comment: user1879408 I switch jsone_encode to simple string, now it fit your needs. Please, accept it if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dimitry, not exactly what I was looking for, but a great hint to find the solution:

```
$client->request(
    'PUT', '/test', array(), array(),
    array(
        'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json',
        'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'
    ),
   '{"id":"34"}'
);
```

Your solution had one empty array to much and the idea was to pass in JSON as string!

Thanks a lot! Cheers